# A way to use a string for creating new classes

Tags: java, reflection

I have a string with the name of a class, is there a way (writing in Java) to use that string when creating a new instance of that class, to do something like this:
*object obj = new dataInString*.
So the dataInString is parsed from the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean something like [`Class.forName(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)? Quoting the javadoc of the method:

> Returns the `Class` object associated with the class or interface with the given string name. Invoking this method is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> Class.forName(className, true, currentLoader)
> ```
>
> where `currentLoader` denotes the defining class loader of the current class.
>
> For example, the following code fragment returns the runtime `Class` descriptor for the class named `java.lang.Thread`:
>
> ```
> Class t = Class.forName("java.lang.Thread")
> ```
>
> A call to `forName("X")` causes the class named X to be initialized.

And then, call [`Class#newInstance()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) on the returned `Class` (it must have an empty constructor).

> Creates a new instance of the class represented by this `Class`  object. The class is instantiated as if by a `new`  expression with an empty argument list. The class is initialized if it has not already been initialized.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the class has a no-args constructor, then the following should do the trick

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("someclass");
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

If you need to create the object using a different constructor, then you will need to do something like this:

```
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor(ArgClass.class, Integer.TYPE);
Object obj = ctor.newInstance(arg, Integer.valueOf(42));
```

There are a number of checked exceptions that need to be handled in either case ...

Comment: I think, you meant Integer.TYPE instead of Integer.CLASS. Also, I would recommend against the new Integer(...) if using Java 1.5 or higher (since you are using varargs, that would be the case): Either rely on autoboxing or use Integer.valueOf(...) - this avoids creating new objects for commonly used instances.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [reflection](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Thanks, that is the direction I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use reflections to instantiate objects. A simple class.forName("com.blah.blah") should be a good starting point to look for more information on reflections.